# Which is better to remove alpha characters from string for long strings - RegEx vs IsLetter

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, loops

Please let me know which one is better in performance RegEx or Loop with IsLetter.

I have tried this both methods and found RegEx is taking a little more time then For Loop...

```
Dim vStr1 As String, vStr2 As New StringBuilder

vStr1 = "Testadfasdfadsfasdfadsfas12312dfadsfdsa23131fadsfsadfsadf1sss 23 -1234"    

Method 1
-------------------
vStr2.Clear()
For Each vChr In vStr1
    If Char.IsLetter(vChr) = False Then vStr2.Append(vChr)
Next
vStr1 = vStr2.ToString
-------------------------

Method 2
-------------------
vStr1 = Regex.Replace(vStr1, "[A-Za-z^s]", "")
```

Comment: Better for what? Performance? Low number of lines of code? Something else?

Comment: In performance wise to edit large number of rows in datatable with big strings...

Comment: Datatable? This smells of solving the problem the wrong place. If you are reading the contents from a database and persisting it after, my guess is that you are looking to optimize the wrong code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop method will be faster. No need to compile the regex for one and RegEx's nearly always loose in these simple cases.

In the Method 1 if you set the capacity of vStr2 to the length of vStr1 it will avoid a slow memory allocation.

```
Dim vStr1 As String
vStr1 = "Testadfasdfadsfasdfadsfas12312dfadsfdsa23131fadsfsadfsadf1sss 23 -1234"
Dim vStr2 As New StringBuilder(vStr1.Length)
```

Also if you are doing this multiple times use vStr2.Clear() rather than throwing away the StringBuilder and allocating a new one.

In Method 2
You could improve things by compiling the RegEx. I'm also not sure why you have ^s in the character list, won't that give a different result?

Comment: Thanks Martin Brown, I have done 10-15 performance test on different columns of a large datatable and always find string functions are faster than RegEx... It seems I have to use string functions to archive my goal in a better way. Please give me your advice. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to find out:

1. Download LINQPad from http://www.linqpad.net/
2. Write 2 functions that do replace
3. Check their performance by using `Stopwatch` over 10000 iterations

Comment: I have tried that with stopwatch and found RegEx is taking more time then for loop...  I have posted this question to get expert advice before using any method.

Comment: Expert advice would be to consider big-O cost analysis of both approaches. Failing that, use the pragmatic approach here and replace linqpad with your execution engine and 10000 with a constant from hour own situation